# Paypal and Payoneer users' validation API

Tags: api, validation, paypal

I wrote a web-site and I want to connect the users at some point to there Paypal and Payoneer accounts.
I saw some very old posts (even in Stack overflow) that said it wasn't possible.

Does someone know if something has changes? Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the API myself, but here is the link for the [Paypal Account Authentication API](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/authentication). I couldn't find much about Payoneer, except that they are thinking about [making a SDK](http://community.payoneer.com/topic/131-payoneer-sdk/).

Comment: "or if you would like to be considered for live approval" What does that mean ? I have a c# project. Where can I download the relevant payPal dll ?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what that means... You should try contacting their [support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/). You can [download the SDK here](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks).